# Create and Secure AWS EB Application with multiple Environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc, flask-restful

## Now

I've developed an application that works on top a set of services that are collecting and elaborating data collected from the Internet (app_one, app_two, app_three) and then I have a core App that merges and visualizes that information (app_core).
[image]
This project is based on top of AWS Elastic Beanstalk, having for each App its own git.
To handle the connection between Apps I've (insecurely) mapped each service with a subdomain.

## What I would like to do

I will love to move development of this project inside a VPC and secure the interfaces between the REST Flask Apps (one,two,three) and the Core App.

[image]

## My questions

1) How I can avoid to give a public ip to my eb-enviroment? Every time I run:

```
eb create myenvname --instance_type t2.XXX
```

it automatically set up a public IP. Can I move it inside the VPS behind and Internet Gateway?

2) If there is a way to securely move those services behind the gateway,
how can I address HTTP requests between those Apps? 
I don't have subdomains here internally, Should I need to use the private IP's(I don't think so)? There is a way to privately address those services? like in Docker refer to the single docker as " app_one/ ".

I'm sorry if those questions could sound naive, but I have got a background in a completely other area of interest

thanks a lot

### Edit

I add project folder structure:

```
--+/MyAPP 
  |
  |---+/app_one     # single env folder
  |   ...
  |
  |---+/app_two .   # single env folder
  |   ...
  |
  |---+/app_three   # single env folder
  |   ...
  |
  |---+/app_core    # single env folder
      |--/env       # virtual env 
      |--+/app_core # flask application
         |--/lib
         |--+/.elasticbeanstalk # eb folder
         |  |--config.yml
         |--application.py
         |--requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to launch your apps either into a private subnet or set the configration flag `AssociatePublicIpAddress = false`.

## How to set that flag?

> ## [Configuration Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-before.html)
>
> Use .ebextensions to configure options that are required to make your application work, and provide default values for other options that can be overridden at a higher level of precedence. Options specified in .ebextensions have the lowest level of precedence and are overridden by settings at any other level.
>
> To use configuration files, create a folder named .ebextensions at the top level of your project's source code. Add a file with the extension .config and specify options in the following manner:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace:  namespace
      option_name:  option name
      value:  option value
    - namespace:  namespace
      option_name:  option name
      value:  option value
```

Set the flag `AssociatePublicIpAddress = false`

`.ebextensions/app.config`

```
option_settings:
  - namespace:  aws:ec2:vpc
    option_name:  AssociatePublicIpAddress
    value:  false
```

## How to set the `Subnet`

`.ebextensions/app.config`

```
option_settings:
  - namespace:  aws:ec2:vpc
    option_name:  VPCId
    value:  vpc-4545121
  - namespace:  aws:ec2:vpc
    option_name:  Subnets
    value:  sub-45455565
```

## + Resources

- [Configuration Options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html)
- [General Options for All Environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html)
- [Advanced Environment Customization with Configuration Files `.ebextensions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html)
- [Getting to Know and Love AWS Elastic Beanstalk Configuration Files `.ebextensions`](https://medium.com/trisfera/getting-to-know-and-love-aws-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files-ebextensions-9a4502a26e3c)

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: thank you for the answer, I will try to mess up a little bit with the information you gave me. I've edited the post with the folder structure. Where I should add the .ebextensions/app.config? thanks again

Comment: Where to add the configuration: https://medium.com/trisfera/getting-to-know-and-love-aws-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files-ebextensions-9a4502a26e3c  That link will help a lot!

Comment: Wow! I've to study a lot. Thank you for all the hints. I let you know

Comment: I've found also this, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebcli-compose.html.  I'm still having issue understand how to address http request between resources. Where I should set the name of the resouce? In the config.yml?